# How to get a css rule with php?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Here is an example of my stylesheet:

```
#thing {
display: none;
}
```

What I would like to do is, with PHP, I would like to get what display is. I can do this with Javascript, but I would like to know how to do it in PHP as I am more confident with it. 
Here is how I would do it with Javascript:

document.getElementById(id).style.display;

So basically, I would like to do that but in PHP.
Thanks, and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 4):

PHP is a server-side language, it can't be executed on the client (i.e.: in the web browser) and therefore cannot be used to obtain attributes that only exist on the client (i.e.: the attributes of a given CSS rule.)

Comment: @Jared G - Not a problem. Incidentally, JavaScript is perfect for such client-side issues, so it's probably worth learning more about JavaScript so that you have both server and client side programming experience. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No Dear, You can't do in php because php is server side script and javascript is client side you can't do it php and why you want it in php? if you want conditional then you can echo with php but have to have use javascript at all

Comment: I wanted to do it in PHP because I'm for fluent in it, but from all these answers, I'm off to Javascript school! (aka some random tut online)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do such a thing, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load a php file as a css file and make things generate dynamically. I wouldn't advise you to but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well PHP don't access the DOM like js does, so the easiest way would be to write out the css in php and make whatever property you need a variable. Not a very solid solution, so avoid it if you can.